# Javascript form data not updating Mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

**EDIT**

Ive now got the following - but still it does not work

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function(){

var jsPostcode = document.login.getElementsByName("postcode").value;
var jsEmail = document.login.getElementsByName("email").value;
var formdata = {postcode:jsPostcode,email:jsEmail};


                $.ajax(
                {
                type: "POST",
                url: "database.php", //Should probably echo true or false depending if it could do it
                data : formdata,
                success: function(feed) {
                  if (feed!="true") {
                     // DO STUFF
                  } else {
                    console.log(feed);
                     // WARNING THAT IT WASN'T DONE
                  }
                }}}};

</script>
```

=================================================================

ORIGINAL QUESTION FOLLOWS

I'm trying to take in data using a form and send some of this to a Mysql database. I cant use the action keyword in the form as that is being used to complete authentication therefore I am trying to use ajax and jquery. I have got to a point where I know I am close to cracking it but I'm not sure what is wrong. Please see my files below. First off the main file login.php is below:

Form Follows (login.php)

```
<?php
   $mac=$_POST['mac'];
   $ip=$_POST['ip'];
   $username=$_POST['username'];
   $linklogin=$_POST['link-login'];
   $linkorig=$_POST['link-orig'];
   $error=$_POST['error'];
   $chapid=$_POST['chap-id'];
   $chapchallenge=$_POST['chap-challenge'];
   $linkloginonly=$_POST['link-login-only'];
   $linkorigesc=$_POST['link-orig-esc'];
   $macesc=$_POST['mac-esc'];
if (isset($_POST['postcode'])) {
    $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
}
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}
?>

**SOME HTML HERE**


<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

var js-postcode = document.login.getElementsByName("postcode").value;
var js-email = document.login.getElementsByName("email").value;
var formdata = {postcode:js-postcode,email:js-email};

        $("button").click(function(){
                $.ajax(
                {
                type: "POST",
                url: "database.php", //Should probably echo true or false depending if it could do it
                data : formdata,
                success: function(feed) {
                  if (feed!="true") {
                     // DO STUFF
                  } else {
                    console.log(feed);
                     // WARNING THAT IT WASN'T DONE
                  }
                }}}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<table width="100%" style="margin-top: 10%;">
        <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <table width="240" height="240" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc; padding: 0px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="bottom" height="175" colspan="2">
<!-- removed $(if chap-id) $(endif)  around OnSubmit -->
                <form name="login" action="<?php echo $linkloginonly; ?>" method="post" onSubmit="return doLogin()" >
                        <input type="hidden" name="dst" value="<?php echo $linkorig; ?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="popup" value="true" />

                        <table width="100" style="background-color: #ffffff">
                                <tr><td align="right">login</td>
                                <td><input style="width: 80px" name="username" type="text" value="<?php echo $username; ?>"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr><td align="right">password</td>
                                <td><input style="width: 80px" name="password" type="password"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr><td align="right">Postcode</td>
                                <td><input style="width: 80px" name="postcode" type="text" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr><td align="right">Email</td>
                                <td><input style="width: 80px" name="email" type="text" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <td><button><input type="submit" value="OK" /></button></td>
                                </tr>
                        </table>
                </form>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        </td>
        </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
  document.login.username.focus();
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and called file database.php is as follows:

```
<?php 

if ((isset($_POST['postcode'])) && (isset($_POST['email']))) {

   $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];

  $connect= new mysqli_connect('xx','xx','xx','xx');


  if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    echo "There was a problem connecting to MySQL: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error;
  }

  if (!($sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO visitors(postcode,email) VALUES(postcode,email)"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
  }

  //NOTE: the "ss" part means that $postcode and $email are strings (mysql is expecting datatypes of strings). For example, if $postcode is an integer, you would do "is" instead.

  if (!$sql->bind_param("ss", $postcode, $email)) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $sql->errno . ") " . $sql->error;
  } 


  if (!$sql->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $sql->errno . ") " . $sql->error;

  } 


} else {

  echo 'Variables did not send through ajax.'; // any echoed values would be sent back to javascript and stored in the 'response' variable of your success or fail functions for testing.

}

?>
```

Please help - all assistance greatly appreciated

Comment: You're setting the `formdata` variable when the page loads, not when the user clicks on the button.

Comment: Ah ok how can i adjust it to set it on click?

Comment: `js-postcode` is not a valid variable name. It actually says `js` minus `postcode` now... You should use camelCase or snake_case in js

Comment: Ah ok pevara thanks Ill try adjusting those

Comment: @PaulaLivingstone Assign the variables inside the `.click()` function.

Comment: You can also use `$("form").serialize()` to get all the inputs in the form.

Comment: You also need to put all that Javascript inside `$(document).ready()` or move the script to the end of the HTML.

Comment: Ive added a document.ready, changed to camel case on the offending variables but still no luck...